# Matching label with sentence in json format

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, jsonlines

I have a huge list of dictionaries with data labeled as follows

```
{'id': 2,
 'text': '"The hotel has many restaurants to enjoy a meal. My husband and I went to the Japanese restaurant and we only found sushi. Considering that it is an international hotel, they should have a larger variety of options.',
 'label': [[0, 46, 'general services'], [47, 214, 'japanese food']]},
```

And I want to create the next output, split the sentence and put the label in front of it, like this.

```
The hotel has many restaurants to enjoy a meal , general services.
My husband and I went to the Japanese restaurant and we only found sushi. Considering that it is an international hotel, they should have a larger variety of options, japanese food
```

I used the code:

```
for x in data[2]['label']:
  print(data[2]['text'][x[0]:x[1]],x[2])
```

But I want to generalize this, for the whole data set. I really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have list of dictionaries as you said in your question you can do:

```py
data = [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "The hotel has many restaurants to enjoy a meal. My husband and I went to the Japanese restaurant and we only found sushi. Considering that it is an international hotel, they should have a larger variety of options.",
        "label": [[0, 46, "general services"], [47, 214, "japanese food"]],
    }
]

for d in data:
    for (start, end, label) in d["label"]:
        print("{}, {}".format(d["text"][start:end], label))
```

Prints:

```
The hotel has many restaurants to enjoy a meal, general services
 My husband and I went to the Japanese restaurant and we only found sushi. Considering that it is an international hotel, they should have a larger variety of options., japanese food
```

---

EDIT: Alternative output:

```py
out = []
for d in data:
    for (start, end, label) in d["label"]:
        out.append(
            {"idx": d["id"], "label": label, "sentence": d["text"][start:end]}
        )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "idx": 2,
        "label": "general services",
        "sentence": "The hotel has many restaurants to enjoy a meal",
    },
    {
        "idx": 2,
        "label": "japanese food",
        "sentence": " My husband and I went to the Japanese restaurant and we only found sushi. Considering that it is an international hotel, they should have a larger variety of options.",
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In case I need the next format  ```{'idx': 2,
 'label': "general services",
 'sentence': "The hotel has many restaurants to enjoy a meal."}``` how should I modify the code you brought? Thank you!